# How would you achieve this 3d hover effect?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a 3d mouseover effect when you're over a DIV. Here's what it's look like for now

http://jsfiddle.net/6TNBU/

I would like to know how I could make in sort that the lower-left and top-right corner would have a cleaner shadow, oblique style. I thought maybe load a triangle on those corners but I would like to know if there's any other way I could achieve that.

Thanks

Comment: You could always clone the shadow element as you animate the top layer, positioning the clones as needed to create the 3D effect. Seems hacky though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using pseudo-elements, there's the `::before` and `::after` (although note that, as I recall, IE doesn't recognise the double-colon declaration, so you'd really have to use `:before` and `:after`):

```
#box::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f90;
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;
    border-right: 10px solid black;
}

#box::after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    border-right: 10px solid white;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6TNBU/1/).

Comment: This was exactly what I was working on.  The only suggestion I would make is to add a wrapper so that you can use the effect when it is not at the top-left of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/6TNBU/3/

Comment: Any IE7 and IE8 compatible way to do it? :D

Comment: Oh well nevermind with single : it works with IE8 but not IE7... to hell with IE7 :D

Comment: How could we achieve multiple boxes like theses? Floating one each other

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be fun to try the "blocklets" approach, ie, use `div`s to create the appearance of 3D by layering `div`s between the background and the box, with the in-betweens being offset from the parent by one pixel top and left to create the appearance of depth.

Note, I'm not suggesting this a great approach, as a number of issues could impact performance. However, I was pleasantly surprised to see that I could get relatively good performance with the below code, and yes, it appears to work (as-is) in IE7/8/9, as well as FF10 and Chrome 17.

So if it's useful to you, I'm glad to hear that, although I would hasten to add it's really just a jumping-off/starting point. There are some known issues I have observed, such as multiple boxes cause the animation to kind've fall apart. But it *appears* to work alright with a single box, and I imagine with some work it could be made to work better, and could even be ported to a plugin (if someone so desired).

Let me know if you have any questions or if you see anything that can/should be fixed, or if you think it's stupid/pointless/[just turrible](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UY4LvTv_83E) and can explain why.

**HTML**

Basic markup:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>​
```

**CSS**

I added the borders because I thought it looked better:

```
.shadow {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.threed {
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.box {
    width: 298px;
    height: 298px;
    background: #cacaca;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-left: 1px solid #acacac;
    border-top: 1px solid #acacac;
}​
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    var $threed = $('<div class="threed">'),
        $shadow = $('<div class="shadow">'),
        offset = 0;

    var init = function($jq, distance, speed){
        $jq.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                $threeds,
                $shadow_clone = $shadow.clone(),
                $threed_clone,
                borderlw = parseInt($this.css('border-left-width')),
                borderrw = parseInt($this.css('border-right-width')),
                bordertw = parseInt($this.css('border-top-width')),
                borderbw = parseInt($this.css('border-bottom-width')),
                width = parseInt($this.innerWidth()) + borderlw + borderrw,
                height = parseInt($this.innerHeight()) + bordertw + borderbw,
                dimensions = {height: height, width: width};

            $shadow_clone.css({
                height: height + distance, 
                width: width + distance}
            );

            $this.data('distance', distance).wrap($shadow_clone);

            for (var i = 0; i <= distance; i++) {
                var $threed_clone = $threed.clone();

                $this.before($threed_clone);
                $threed_clone.css(dimensions).data('dimensions', {
                    left: i, top: i
                });
            }

            $this.data('threeds', $this.siblings('.threed'));

            $this.mouseenter(function(){
                var offset = 0,
                    properties = {
                        left: distance, 
                        top: distance
                    },
                    options = {
                        duration: speed, 
                        step: goUp, 
                        complete: finishThreeD
                    };

                $(this).stop().animate(properties, options);
            })
            .mouseleave(function(){
                var properties = {
                        left: 0, 
                        top: 0
                    },
                    options = {
                        duration: speed, 
                        step: goDown, 
                        complete: finishTwoD
                    };

                $(this).stop().animate(properties, options);
            });
        });
    };

    var goUp = function(){
        var _offset = parseInt(this.style.left);

        if (_offset > offset) {
            offset = _offset;

            $($(this).data().threeds[offset - 1])
                .prevAll('.threed').each(function(){
                    $(this).css($(this).data().dimensions);
                });
        }
    };

    var finishThreeD = function() {
        $(this).data().threeds.each(function(){
            $(this).css($(this).data().dimensions);
        });
    };

    var goDown = function (){
        var _offset = parseInt(this.style.left);

        if (_offset < offset) {
            offset = _offset;

            $($(this).data().threeds[offset - 1])
                .nextAll('.threed').css({top: 0, left: 0});

            if (offset === 0) {
                $(this).data().threeds.css({top: 0, left: 0});
            }
        }
    };

    var finishTwoD = function (){
        $(this).data().threeds.css({top: 0, left: 0});

        offset = 0;
    };

    var inc = 1;

    $('.box').each(function(){
        init($(this), 10 * inc, 100 * (2.5 * inc));
        inc++;
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zuppm/

Comment: Nice way to do multiple 3d boxes +1